# Rails Self referencing using non-primary key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, self-reference

Please help.

I have a self referencing model and want the foreign key to refer to a non-primary key that is scoped.

In the list table, I have a sequence_id column which contains the incremental id of the list that is only unique in a listset. Meaning the same sequence_id can be seen for list of another listset. However, as this sequence_id is not unique throughout the table, I  didn't make it a primary key.

How do I achieve the self-referencing relation using this non-primary key?

Thank you very much.

**Model:**

```
 Class Listset
       has_many :lists, :dependent => :delete_all
       has_many :items, :through => :lists
    end

    Class List
       belongs_to :listset

       belongs_to :parentList, :class_name => "List"
       has_many :childList, :class_name => "List", foreign_key => "parent"

       has_many :items, :dependent => :delete_all
    end

    Class item
        belongs_to :list
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you clarify what you are asking about the `sequence_id`?

This should help with your self-referencing relation:

```
class List < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :listset
  belongs_to :parent,      :class_name => "List"
  has_many   :child_lists, :class_name => "List", :foreign_key => "parent_id"
  # etc...
end
```

This assumes you have a `parent_id` column in the database table.

The convention in Rails is to underscore named relations, i.e. `:child_lists` instead of `:childList`.

Using `belongs_to :parent` indicates to ActiveRecord to look for the `parent_id` column in the lists table, which should be the foreign key referenced in the `has_many` relationship.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt reply. I'll take note about the naming convention. Thanks for pointing it out. What I'm trying to achieve is for ActiveRecord to look for sequence_id instead of parent_id as the parent column keeps the sequence_id, that is not a primary key, and not the id of the parent which is the primary key.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you already know how to model the self-referencing relation using primary keys. Each `List` simply has a `parent_id` that refers to some other `Lists`'s `id` (which is a primary key). I think what you're asking is whether you can model the self-referencing relation using the non-primary key `sequence_id` instead of the default primary key `id`.

*Conceptually*, this is possible because each record in the `List` model would be uniquely identified by both its `sequence_id` *and* its `listset_id`, the reason being that `sequence_id` is unique within the scope of a `listset_id`.

However, I don't think you can safely manipulation `belongs_to` to find a `List`'s parent in this way. According to [railsguides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-types-of-associations),

> ... by declaring that one model belongs_to another, you instruct Rails to maintain Primary Key–Foreign Key information between instances of the two models...

That is, `belongs_to` expects to find records using a foreign key that is a primary key. While you could attempt to make `belongs_to` identify the parent based on the `listset_id` scope and `sequence_id` with something like

```
belongs_to :parent_list, foreign_key: :parent_id, class_name: "List", conditions: proc { {:listset_id => listset_id, :sequence_id => parent_id} }
```

this might lead to unexpected behaviour, as `belongs_to` still expects to use a primary key to identify the associated model.

Though, I'm not entirely sure if this is what you were going for. Let us know.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt reply. Yes that is what I'm trying to achieve. But sadly, nothing happened when I tried to get the children list by calling list.childList

Comment: You still need to define `child_list` properly. The above `belongs_to` will only give you the parent. For the children, try `has_many :child_lists, foreign_key: :parent_id, class_name: "List", conditions: proc { {:listset_id => listset_id} }`. I haven't tried this myself, so I'm not sure that it will work.

Comment: I tried this [ belongs_to :parentList, :class_name => "List", :conditions => proc { {:listset_id => listset_id, :parent => sequence_id} } ] and [ has_many :childList, :class_name => "List", foreign_key => "parent", :conditions => proc { {:listset_id => listset_id, :sequence_id=> parent } }  } ] but nothing happen when I tried to get the children list by calling list.childList